# Connecting Android device for debugging

Tags: android, linux, linux-device-driver

Hi i know how to connect and configure an Android hardware device with a Linux PC and to execute an app developed in Eclipse. But my question is we want to create "51-android.rules" file and to add the content

```
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

what is the meaning of the above mentioned thing and what each attribute mentions.

Its just my curiosity to know new things. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the link below.

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

"the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node." from android.com